# Flutter tcp socket seems to loose 1-2 bytes when sending big data

Tags: flutter, sockets, tcp

I've encountered this issue and i can't figure out what's going on.
I have a server which works with tcp socket connection. It stores some images and i want them to be sent to my flutter application.
I tried 2 different ways:

1. I listen to the socket untill the packets arrives completely (the server sends some characters at the end of the message representing that the message is finished).
2. I send the length of the message to the application and listen untill i read all the data.

In both of the ways, I can see that many time i loose 1 or 2 bytes of data (rarely 3 or 4).
I also noticed that it seems like that my application misses those bytes of data at the beginning of the packets i send. (for example if the message to be sent is "AAAABBBBCCCC" and it is split because of the algorithm in 2 messages, i receive something like "AAAABB", "BCCCC" where if i join them i miss a 'B').
If i try with a  c# application i developed everything goes fine and i can receive all the data everytime.

The code i use in the flutter application to listen is this: (way 1 of the two ways i explained above)

```
socket.listen((List<int> event) async {
      String received=(utf8.decode(event));
      message += received;
      if(message.contains(eos)){   //IF THE MESSAGE CONTAINS THE LIMITER CHARACTERS THEN I CALL A FUNCTION
        callback(message.split(eos)[0]);
      }
    });
```

Comment: nono the problem isn't it, "eos" is the character delimiter so i don't want to use it in my function. By the way i found a "solution" as I wrote below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something really interesting! The problem was all in the emulator!
In fact using my phone i can read all the data everytime!
So beware when you are using the emulator and sending/listening for data over tcp sockets.
Thank you all by the way, I hope this will be useful to someone.